# trying to understand event.preventDefault in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").click(function (event) {         
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/">Go to dotnetheaven.com </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here(http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), it is said: **If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.**

Question:

For the above code, the event means 'click'? 'the default action' is openning the URL? Am I understanding correctly? Because I wonder why alert still shows up after `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Yes, the default action for clicking an anchor is navigating to its `href`.

Comment: `alert` is not the default action, so why shouldn't it show up? :-)

Comment: @KnutMarius [return false and preventDefault are not the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` is not provided by jQuery.

Comment: @techfoobar: It is, as jQuery passes a [custom `jqEvent` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to the handler, and `preventDefault` will call the native one (or the M$ equivalent)

Comment: @Bergi - Yes, you're right in that respect. But `preventDefault()` is available in the native event object as well, so the difference is not very significant in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default action is to open the URL.

`event.preventDefault()` will prevent this.

The `alert()` is not the default action, this is one you have specified (as you've put it in the click event handler). Therefore this will still action.

Answer (score 2):

> For the above code, the event means 'click'? 'the default action' is
>   openning the URL? Am I understanding correctly?

Yup.

> Because I wonder why alert still shows up after
>   event.preventDefault().

The rest of the function will still execute, `event.preventDefault()` does *not* return.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour is to change `location.href` to `/` which is being prevented using `.preventDefault()`, Your event handler will continue to execute after preventing the default action.